# page footer orientation

Tags: crystal-reports, footer

I have a report containing 4 subreports. The first two are in portrait orientation and the last two are in landscape. I have a page footer for the entire report that I would liked centered for every page, however I don't know how to conditionally format it to center based on the page orientation. Any suggestions?
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not print both portrait and landscape reports in the SAME Crystal Reports template.